# Using ight join and inner join in Access

Tags: ms-access, join, right-join

I want to use inner join and right join statement.
[image]

This is the relation of my tables.
I'm trying but it says join statement is not supported.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT ProjectName, HoursWorked, FirstName, LastName
FROM (PROJECT AS P INNER JOIN ASSIGNMENT AS A ON P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID)
RIGHT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E ON A.EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber
```

Someone use right join statement iteratively but it didnt' work for me.
Ms API says both left and right join can also use with inner join.
Why it didn't work?

Comment: What is your current error/output?

Comment: Um... Its language is Korean, so I'm not sure but it seems 'The join statement is not supported'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in the sub select:

```
SELECT ProjectName, HoursWorked, FirstName, LastName
FROM (PROJECT AS P RIGHT JOIN ASSIGNMENT AS A ON P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID)
RIGHT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E ON A.EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> A LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN may be nested inside an INNER JOIN, but an INNER JOIN may not be nested inside a LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: It didn't work. It has error, but it's Korean.. I don't know how to translate this.

Comment: I guess `P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID
RIGHT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E
    ON A.EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber access syntax error (missing operator) in query expression`

Comment: @YooInhyeok Try using `RIGHT JOIN` everywhere.

Comment: Ms Access supports right join. Right join works well. I chekced. But failed on that syntax

Comment: I'm sorry I confused. But why right join not supported? I mean, 
`SELECT ProjectName, FirstName, LastName, HoursWorked
FROM (PROJECT AS P INNER JOIN ASSIGNMENT AS A ON P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID) LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E ON A.EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber
ORDER BY P.ProjectID, A.EmployeeNumber;
` works

Comment: but 
`SELECT ProjectName, FirstName, LastName, HoursWorked
FROM (PROJECT AS P INNER JOIN ASSIGNMENT AS A ON P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID) RIGHT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E ON A.EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber
ORDER BY P.ProjectID, A.EmployeeNumber;` NOT.

Comment: The only difference of them is INNER / RIGHT JOIN.